# How to get mass bash scripts to run one after the other

Tags: bash, shell, large-data

I have a 2 processes that I need to run one after the other on a large number of files.

```
for file in ` basename -a /path/to/some/data-*`; do

        #Manages the number of jobs and cores
        SCRIPTNAME=/path_to_my/script.sh
        NCORES=90
        while [ $(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep $SCRIPTNAME | wc -l) -ge $NCORES ]; do
            sleep 1m
        done
        echo "${SCRIPTNAME} ${file}"
        bash $SCRIPTNAME $file &
done
```

After all of those files get done I'd like to run another file in a similar way but I can't just add another for loop after this one because it will start before the others complete.
How can I run the next for loop after there are no more processes running from the first loop?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you look into [snakemake](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

It's initially made for the case of having to analyze a large set of biological samples in parallel, where some of the steps have dependencies on prior steps.
Like this, if your inputfile1 is already finished with step1, snakemake would already start step2 for inputfile 1, even if step 1 for inputfile2 might still be running.
Depending on how many inputfiles and how many computational recources you have, this approach might save you some valuable time.

Otherwise, if snakemake is not an option I would go for Erans approach.

Or maybe have your first script add a line to a dummie file as a very last command, and have a while loop checking every 30sec (or more) if this file contains the same amount of lines as your inputdata before it starts the second run.
Like this it will also not start, if one of your first scripts fails.

This could look something like

```
tot=$(ls /path/to/some/data-* | wc -l)
while sleep 30; do
    lines=$(wc -l dummie.txt)
    if [ "$tot" == "$lines"]; then
        echo -e "All jobs from first script finished! You can now start second script"
    fi
done
```

I'm sure there are more elegant ways, but this is what comes to my mind right now.

Answer (score 1):

The `bash $SCRIPTNAME $file &` returns the process ID of the background process. Collect all the IDs and use the `wait` command to hold until all are done.